# Why is this not a B flat fingering on the flute?

Tags: fingering, flute

I am learning the flute and I found that all these are accepted Bb fingerings:

[image]

My question is why is this not an "accepted" fingering for Bb, which to me is the most obvious one (given that that's what's actually done by all those other fingerings):

[image]

Comment: Curious which website you got these precise fingering images from.

Comment: @Dekkadeci, it's from AndrewScottMusic.com: https://andrewscottmusic.com/free-fingering-chart-for-the-flute-download/